Create a 'sub' table of contents for a section. Should include only the contents of that section (i.e., subsections and subsubsections, not sections)
I am preparing a document with many sections, subsections and subsubsections. To make the document easy to navigate I want to have a global table of contents that contains only sections and subsections. Within each section I want to have a local table of contents that contains only the subsections and subsubsections of that section and does not repeat/include the section itself. Preferably the local table of contents would not have a title. Finally, the contents of the global and local tables of contents should be clickable to jump to the specific pages, for example using hyperref. See an example MWE below.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    The document title/cover page
    
    \newpage 
    
    % Full table of contents (inclde entire document)
    % If this table of contents only included sections and subsesctions 
    % (not subsubsections) that would be ideal
    \tableofcontents 
    
    \newpage 
    
    \section{The first section}
    Some brief introduction to the first section goes here.
    
    % This table of centents should include everything from subsesctions downwards
    % I.e. it must include subsubsections
    % The contents should be clickable for navigation using hyperref
    \noindent Table of contents of the first section's subsections goes here.
    
    % Start of the content of section one
    \subsection{The first subsection of the first section}
    
    \subsubsection{The first subsubsection of the first subsection of the first section}
    
    \subsubsection{The second subsubsection of the first subsection of the first section}
    
    \subsection{The second subsection of the first section}
    
    \subsubsection{The first subsubsection of the second subsection of the first section}
    
    \subsubsection{The second subsubsection of the second subsection of the first section}
    
    \newpage
    
    \section{The second section}
    Some brief introduction to the second section goes here.
    
    % This table of centents should include everything from subsesctions downwards
    % I.e. it must include subsubsections
    % The contents should be clickable for navigation using hyperref
    \noindent Table of contents of the second section's subsections goes here.
    
    % Start of the content of section two
    \subsection{The first subsection of the second section}
    
    \subsubsection{The first subsubsection of the first subsection of the second section}
    
    \subsubsection{The second subsubsection of the first subsection of the second section}
    
    \subsection{The second subsection of the second section}
    
    \subsubsection{The first subsubsection of the second subsection of the second section}
    
    \subsubsection{The second subsubsection of the second subsection of the second section}
    
\end{document}


Have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc

Other possibilities: Insert Table of Contents in chapter (can be adapted for article), Specify minitoc for each chapter (can be adapted for article) etc.

Here is as suggested in comments using etoc.  Refer to its documentation (texdoc etoc) for more.  Pass option linktoc=all to hyperref if you want page numbers to be hyperlinked in the tocs.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}
    
    The document title/cover page
    
    \newpage 
    
    % Full table of contents (inclde entire document)
    % If this table of contents only included sections and subsesctions 
    % (not subsubsections) that would be ideal
\etocsetnexttocdepth{subsection}
    \tableofcontents 
    
    \newpage 
    
    \section{The first section}
    Some brief introduction to the first section goes here.
    
    % This table of centents should include everything from subsesctions downwards
    % I.e. it must include subsubsections
    % The contents should be clickable for navigation using hyperref
    \noindent Table of contents of the first section's subsections goes here.
    
\etocsettocstyle
  {}% before (nothing; default does something such as \contentsname\par with bold face
  {}% after (nothing)
\localtableofcontents

    % Start of the content of section one
    \subsection{The first subsection of the first section}
    
    \subsubsection{The first subsubsection of the first subsection of the first section}
    
    \subsubsection{The second subsubsection of the first subsection of the first section}
    
    \subsection{The second subsection of the first section}
    
    \subsubsection{The first subsubsection of the second subsection of the first section}
    
    \subsubsection{The second subsubsection of the second subsection of the first section}
    
    \newpage
    
    \section{The second section}
    Some brief introduction to the second section goes here.
    
    % This table of centents should include everything from subsesctions downwards
    % I.e. it must include subsubsections
    % The contents should be clickable for navigation using hyperref
    \noindent Table of contents of the second section's subsections goes here.


% no need to repeat \etocsettocstyle here as its configuration still applies
\localtableofcontents
    
    % Start of the content of section two
    \subsection{The first subsection of the second section}
    
    \subsubsection{The first subsubsection of the first subsection of the second section}
    
    \subsubsection{The second subsubsection of the first subsection of the second section}
    
    \subsection{The second subsection of the second section}
    
    \subsubsection{The first subsubsection of the second subsection of the second section}
    
    \subsubsection{The second subsubsection of the second subsection of the second section}
    
\end{document}


next page

